Guess the song, given some code!
i = 0
paths = BinaryTree()

print(input("here") == "home")
i = 1
print(source.indexOf(1))
paths.travel(np.nan)
assert us.age < timedelta(years = 77.5) and us == chr(9829) and us == False

hsv = [[[[[[[(0, 0, 0)]]]]]]]
hsv = [color for color in hsv if not (color[2] > 127)]
assert chr(128123) in i
assert set(it).issubset(sides[1])
assert us.age < timedelta(years = 77.5) and us == chr(9829) and us == False

Can you guess the song based on the lyrics above?
Hint:

 [4, 9, 12, 5, 9, 5, 7, 16, 12, 7, 14, 11]

Meta-hint (for what the hint means):

 root = 440*2**(7/12)  meta = [root*2**(n/12) for n in hint]


The song is

 The Spectre by Alan Walker

Chorus:

print(input("here") == "home")
Is this the place that I call home

print(source.indexOf(1))
To find what I've become?
 Find I (1) inside the source array. Relating to the fact that the variable i changed from 0 to 1
 
paths.travel(np.nan)
Walk along the path unknown
NaN = Not a Number, so we travel a path unknown along the binary tree

assert us.age < timedelta(years = 77.5) and us == chr(9829) and us == False
We live, we love, we lie
77.5 years is the average life expectancy in the US, if the age of "us" is less than that, we are likely to live. 9829 is the decimal number of a Unicode heart. If "Us" is false, we lie.

hsv = [[[[[[[(0, 0, 0)]]]]]]]
hsv = [color for color in hsv if not (color[2] > 127)]
Deep in the dark I don't need the light
The array several levels deep only contains (0, 0, 0), i.e. black in HSV. We dismiss any color if it's Value is greater than 50% (0 = Black, 100% = White), because we don't need the light

assert chr(128123) in i
There's a ghost inside me
Unicode Ghost inside "I" (me).
 
assert set(it).issubset(sides[1])
It all belongs to the other side
 The entire set "it" is a subset of the second side in the sides array

assert us.age < timedelta(years = 77.5) and us == chr(9829) and us == False
We live, we love, we lie

The hint:

 Thanks to Greg Martin in the comments, the numbers in the hint form a melody when interpreted as the number of semitones/half-steps above a fixed pitch - The beginning of the song at hand. The meta-hint gives hertz values.


I’ve added a meta-hint to clarify what the hint means.

Regarding the hint: rot13(Gur ahzoref va gur uvag sbez n zrybql jura vagrecergrq nf gur ahzore bs frzvgbarf/unys-fgrcf nobir n svkrq cvgpu.)
